# Eclipse asking for sudo (wiringPi)

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, sudo, wiringpi

I have written a c code employing wiringpi. I have used eclipse platform for it. I could able to build and binary file is being generated. Once I run the project, it is showing :

> wiringPiSetup: Must be root. (Did you forget sudo?)

It will usually happen even while running through terminal. But I dont know how to add `sudo` to it. Tried it by adding
`sudo gcc -pthread -lwiringPi` in the `Project->properties->C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Cross GCC compiler ->Command`

It is reflecting in the make file. But it is still asking for sudo. How to add it ?

Comment: The message is generated when application is launched, not by compiler. Try opening Eclipse as sudo, or launch your executable with sudo into a terminal.

Comment: couldnt able to open eclipse as sudo, any other method?

Comment: run the application from the command line where the first 5 characters on the command line are: `sudo `  It will then ask you for your password before running the program.